# Dynamically cast the datatype in Pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, casting, databricks

I am creating a parquet file from PostgresSQL and it has everything marked as varchar column. Once we have the file in ADLS, we want to cast the data type according to the data like date, integer, varchar field in Azure databricks using Python/Pyspark.

Same code is need to be utilized by multiple file **with different schema** so wanted a **generic process** with no hardcoded value.

I have user inferSchema=True but its still reading int as String.
So wanted a method to auto cast the fileds

Comment: I edited my answer to include a code sample where a `dataframe( string, int, float, datatime)` varchar columns properly is coerced into the required datypes.

Answer (score 0):

The strategy I have used to find a generalized solution is as follows.

1.First I read in the parquet file as a dataframe. Everything at this stage is string.

2.Convert a small sample i.e. 2 to 10 rows to a pandas dataframe.

3.Pandas has the ability to infer the datatypes of string columns. But it can only do so if we simulate it reading from disk. To do that, we convert the pandas dataframe to a file in memory and read from that file into a new dataframe.

4.Now that the above new readback pandas dataframe has required types. We can proceed. Once issue is it can't handle datetime strings. So convert the `object` columns in pandas into datatime column if possible. Make sure you add your additional custom datatype handling code is here.

5.Convert this pandas dataframe with inferred types into pyspark dataframe.

6.Get the schema of the pyspark dataframe from above.

7.Apply that datatype inferred of each column in the above separately to the original dataframe which we in step 1.

8.One thing to keep in mind is Spark tries to be as generous as possible. So it will use LongType instead of IntType and DoubleType instead of FloatType may be so that all future possible cases as handled.

```
import sys
from pyspark import SparkContext, SQLContext
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
import pandas as pd
import io


sc = SparkContext('local')
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

def print_pandas(dataframe_given):
    with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None,'display.max_columns', None, 'expand_frame_repr', False):
        print("Given pandas dataframe name")
        print(dataframe_given)

### Very Long dataframe which we have reading from a file or database with everything varchar
data1 = [
    ["a1", "1", "101.0", "2023-09-06 17:51:23"],
    ["a2", "2", "223.0", "2025-09-16 17:51:23"],
    ["a3", "4", "10.0", "2023-09-06 17:51:23"],
    ["b1", "6", "256.0", "2025-09-16 17:51:23"],
    ["b2", "11", "1023.0", "2023-09-06 17:51:23"],
    ["b3", "22", "243.0", "2025-09-16 17:51:23"],
    ["c1", "17", "10.0", "2023-09-06 17:51:23"],
    ["c2", "72",  "211.0", "2025-09-16 12:00:23"],
    ["d1", "81", "1023.0", "2023-09-06 17:51:23"],
    ["d3", "92",  "1232.0", "2025-09-16 17:51:23"],

      ]


df1Columns = ["col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"]
df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data=data1, schema = df1Columns)

columns_list = list(df1.columns)
print(columns_list)

print("Showing the dataframe")
df1.show(n=10, truncate=False)
print("Printing the schema of dataframe")
df1.printSchema()

print("Converting a small sample of rows to Pandas dataframe")
pandas_df = df1.limit(2).toPandas()
print_pandas(pandas_df)
print("Datatypes of pandas dataframe before")
print(pandas_df.dtypes)



stream = io.StringIO()
pandas_df.to_csv(stream, index=False)
stream.seek(0)
df_readback = pd.read_csv(stream)
stream.close()

print("Datatypes of pandas dataframe after reading back")
print(df_readback.dtypes)

### if certain column types are still not handled, please handle them in this forloop.
for col in df_readback.columns:
    if df_readback[col].dtype == 'object':
        try:
            df_readback[col] = pd.to_datetime(df_readback[col])
        except ValueError:
            pass


print("Datatypes of pandas dataframe after datatime specific conversion")
print(df_readback.dtypes)
print_pandas(df_readback)


print("Converting pandas dataframe with appropriate datatypes to pyspark dataframe")
small_df_with_dtypes = sqlContext.createDataFrame(df_readback)
small_df_with_dtypes.show(n=10, truncate=False)
print("small_df_with_dtypes with schema")
pandas_inferred_schema = small_df_with_dtypes.schema
print(pandas_inferred_schema)
small_df_with_dtypes.printSchema()


required_df = df1

for struct_field in pandas_inferred_schema:
    column_name = struct_field.name
    column_type = struct_field.dataType
    required_df = required_df.withColumn(column_name, F.col(column_name).cast(column_type))


print("Required dataframe and schema")
required_df.show(n=100, truncate=False)
print("Schema applied is as follows")
print(required_df.schema)
required_df.printSchema()
```

Output :

```
['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4']
Showing the dataframe
+----+----+------+-------------------+
|col1|col2|col3  |col4               |
+----+----+------+-------------------+
|a1  |1   |101.0 |2023-09-06 17:51:23|
|a2  |2   |223.0 |2025-09-16 17:51:23|
|a3  |4   |10.0  |2023-09-06 17:51:23|
|b1  |6   |256.0 |2025-09-16 17:51:23|
|b2  |11  |1023.0|2023-09-06 17:51:23|
|b3  |22  |243.0 |2025-09-16 17:51:23|
|c1  |17  |10.0  |2023-09-06 17:51:23|
|c2  |72  |211.0 |2025-09-16 12:00:23|
|d1  |81  |1023.0|2023-09-06 17:51:23|
|d3  |92  |1232.0|2025-09-16 17:51:23|
+----+----+------+-------------------+

Printing the schema of dataframe
root
 |-- col1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col3: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col4: string (nullable = true)

Converting a small sample of rows to Pandas dataframe
Given pandas dataframe name
  col1 col2   col3                 col4
0   a1    1  101.0  2023-09-06 17:51:23
1   a2    2  223.0  2025-09-16 17:51:23
Datatypes of pandas dataframe before
col1    object
col2    object
col3    object
col4    object
dtype: object
Datatypes of pandas dataframe after reading back
col1     object
col2      int64
col3    float64
col4     object
dtype: object
Datatypes of pandas dataframe after datatime specific conversion
col1            object
col2             int64
col3           float64
col4    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
Given pandas dataframe name
  col1  col2   col3                col4
0   a1     1  101.0 2023-09-06 17:51:23
1   a2     2  223.0 2025-09-16 17:51:23
Converting pandas dataframe with appropriate datatypes to pyspark dataframe
+----+----+-----+-------------------+
|col1|col2|col3 |col4               |
+----+----+-----+-------------------+
|a1  |1   |101.0|2023-09-06 17:51:23|
|a2  |2   |223.0|2025-09-16 17:51:23|
+----+----+-----+-------------------+

small_df_with_dtypes with schema
StructType([StructField('col1', StringType(), True), StructField('col2', LongType(), True), StructField('col3', DoubleType(), True), StructField('col4', TimestampType(), True)])
root
 |-- col1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col2: long (nullable = true)
 |-- col3: double (nullable = true)
 |-- col4: timestamp (nullable = true)

Required dataframe and schema
+----+----+------+-------------------+
|col1|col2|col3  |col4               |
+----+----+------+-------------------+
|a1  |1   |101.0 |2023-09-06 17:51:23|
|a2  |2   |223.0 |2025-09-16 17:51:23|
|a3  |4   |10.0  |2023-09-06 17:51:23|
|b1  |6   |256.0 |2025-09-16 17:51:23|
|b2  |11  |1023.0|2023-09-06 17:51:23|
|b3  |22  |243.0 |2025-09-16 17:51:23|
|c1  |17  |10.0  |2023-09-06 17:51:23|
|c2  |72  |211.0 |2025-09-16 12:00:23|
|d1  |81  |1023.0|2023-09-06 17:51:23|
|d3  |92  |1232.0|2025-09-16 17:51:23|
+----+----+------+-------------------+

Schema applied is as follows
StructType([StructField('col1', StringType(), True), StructField('col2', LongType(), True), StructField('col3', DoubleType(), True), StructField('col4', TimestampType(), True)])
root
 |-- col1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col2: long (nullable = true)
 |-- col3: double (nullable = true)
 |-- col4: timestamp (nullable = true)
```